# The total number of non-negative integers $n$ satisfying the equations $n^2=p+q$ and $n^3=p^2+q^2$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers, is...

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, solution-verification, contest-math

> The total number of non-negative integers $n$ satisfying the equations $n^2=p+q$ and $n^3=p^2+q^2$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers, is...

Case$1$: If both $p$ and $q$ are non-negative integers then,

using, AM of mth power $\ge$ mth power of AM, we get,

$\frac{p^2+q^2}{2}\ge(\frac{p+q}{2})^2\implies \frac{n^3}{2}\ge\frac{n^4}{4}\implies n\le2\implies n=0,1,2$

specifically, $n=0$ when $(p,q)=(0,0)$

$n=1$ when $(p,q)=(1,0) or (0,1)$

$n=2$ when $(p,q)=(2,2)$

Case$2$: when both $p$ and $q$ are negative integers. This case gets rejected because $n^2=p+q$

Case$3$: when one of $p$ and $q$ is positive and the other is negative.

How do we tackle this case?

Comment: $2pq = n^4-n^3 \ge 0$. So they cannot be of opp signs.

Comment: Done @JyrkiLahtonen. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions are constrained mostly because the sum of squares, $p^2+q^2$, grows faster than the sum $p+q$ in comparison to the speeds of growth of $n^3$ vs. $n^2$.

---

Without loss of generality we can assume (in the remaining case) that $p>0>q$. As $p+q=n^2\ge0$ we can deduce that $p\ge -q= |q|$. Given all of this
$$
n^6=(p+q)^3=p^3+3p^2q+3pq^2+q^3\le p^3+3pq^2\le 4p^3.
$$
But also
$$
n^6=(p^2+q^2)^2\ge p^4.
$$
So we have $p^4\le n^6\le 4p^3$ implying that $p\le4$.

This leaves a manageably small set of possibilities for you to check out :-)

Comment: and $2n^3 - n^4 = (p-q)^2 \geq 0$  so $0 \leq n \leq 2$  regardless  of $\pm$ signs on $p,q$

Answer (score 2):

First prove that $p$ and $q$ have the same odd prime factors.

Then prove that no odd prime factor can have different multiplicity in $p$ and $q$.

Conclude that $p$ and $q$ are plus or minus powers of $2$.

Details:

> $2pq = n^4 - n^3$. So every odd prime factor of $n$ divides $pq$. But $n \mid p + q$ so every odd prime factor divides both $p$ and $q$.

> Suppose $r$ is odd and has higher multiplicity in $p$ than $q$, say $r^e$ divides $p$ exactly. Then $r^{e}$ divides $n^2$ exactly and $r^{2e}$ divides $n^3$ exactly, and the multiplicities don't match.

> Therefore $p$ and $q$ are plus or minus powers of $2$. By the same argument above they must have the same multiplicity of $r=2$ so $p = \pm q$ and you can finish from there: The sign must be $+$ and then $n = \frac{p^2 + q^2}{p+q} = p$ and then $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Case 3 does not arise as $2pq = \left(p+q\right)^2-\left(p^2+q^2\right)=n^4-n^3 \ge 0$.

So we only need to consider the case $p,q \ge 0$ which you have covered